# How do I change white pixels to black pixels

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I have a png image like this:

[image]

How can I invert the frame around the waveform so it appears black, without changing the alpha of the waveform itself.  (The waveform part is transparent.)

It probably has something to do with CGCreateImageMask but I can't figure out the exact process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *wf = [UIImage imageNamed:@"waveform.png"];
    [wf drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeXOR alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: I can't... have to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHBCGB) : it explains this kind of operation quite in details, like how to mask an image by colors (see Fig. 11-9 for example) and so on.

Comment: I've read the Quartz 2D guide a million times and honestly I don't understand a word of it.